# angularjs add brackets to array value output

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic3

```
this.fruitArray=[apple,orange,banana];
```

Html

```
<p>{{fruitArray}}</p> // display apple,orange,banana
```

how can i make it display [apple] [orange] [banana] with CSS or angular tags? i don't want to change array value in the code

Comment: `<p ng-repeat="fruit in fruitArray">{{fruit}}</p>`, this will generate: `<p>apple</p><p>orange</p><p>banana</p>`

Comment: Loop is all you need :) [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) helps!

Comment: i feel stupid, i am already using ng-repeat for my list which contain an array field. didn't think i could ng-repeat again inside the list! thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ng-repeat](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp)

```
<label ng-repeat="fruit in fruitArray">{{fruit}} <span>,</span> </label>
```

I use `label` to set them one side by side (in same line) and add `,`

why `label`? `<p>` is `display:block` and set in new line each one

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angularjs then you can achieve your result with the help of ng-repeat like `<p ng-repeat="item in fruitArray">{{item}}</p>`

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by `*ngFor` or `ng-repeat`

Comment: `*ngFor` is for angular 2+ and the OP use angular js

Comment: @לבנימלכה OP is the one who posted this answer

Comment: yess...I write it to othe usres that see this answer and know to distinguish